# How to check which user is responsible for a utilizing a particular port?

Tags: netstat

I wanted to know which user is running a particular port no.
For e.g.

```
netstat -an | grep ':6016'
```

which user is resposible for "6016" port no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use
`netstat -anp | grep ':6016'`
That will give you the pid of the process connected to the port.  Then use 
`ps aux | grep <the pid from the previous command>`
to get the username that the process is running as.

Comment: Thanks @David I am able to see the user even with ps aux | grep ':6017'

Comment: That will only work if the port is specified on the command line of command being run.  Otherwise `ps aux` won't show bound ports, you'll still need `netstat -anp` for that.